# How to subscribe on updates within ReactReduxContext.Consumer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I would like to figure out how to `subscribe` on updates of a stored value it the redux `store`.

So far I've tried something like the following:

```
      <ReactReduxContext.Consumer> 
      {({store}) => {
        console.log('store:', store.getState());
        const p = <p>{store.getState().value}</p>;
        store.subscribe(() => {p.innerText = store.getState().value});
        return p;
      }}
      </ReactReduxContext.Consumer>
```

bumping into the `TypeError: can't define property "innerText": Object is not extensible` error on updates.

So I wonder how to update the contents?

Comment: Is there a reason that you are trying to do this via store.subscribe rather that with the useSelector hook or the connect HOC? I can def write you an answer but I am trying to understand your goals.

Comment: @LindaPaiste, my aim was to learn a way of making use of store on the go, e.g. for debugging purposes or draft cases, by lean and mean means of a few rows of code encapsulated within a close block which may be embedded (butted in) everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things about your code that are just not the way that we do things in React.

React is its own system for interacting with the DOM, so you should not attempt direct DOM manipulation through `.innerText`.  Your code doesn't work because the variable `p` which you create is a React JSX Element rather than a raw HTML paragraph element, so it doesn't have properties like `innerText`.

Instead, you just return the correct JSX code based on `props` and `state`.  The code will get updated any time that props or state change.

The `ReactReduxContext` is used internally by the `react-redux` package.  Unless you have a good reason to use it in your app, I would not recommend it.  There are two built-in ways that you can get a current value of state that is already subscribed to changes.

#### [`useSelector` hook](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector)

(recommended)

```
export const MyComponent1 = () => {
  const value = useSelector(state => state.value);

  return <p>{value}</p>
}
```

#### [`connect` higher-order component](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect)

(needed for class components which cannot use hooks)

```
class ClassComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <p>{this.props.value}</p>
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  value: state.value
});

const MyComponent2 = connect(mapStateToProps)(ClassComponent)
```

#### [`ReactReduxContext`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/accessing-store#using-reactreduxcontext-directly)

(not recommended)

If anyone reading this has a good reason why they should need to use `store.subscribe()`, proper usage would look something like this:

```
const MyComponent3 = () => {
  const { store } = useContext(ReactReduxContext);
  const [state, setState] = useState(store.getState());

  useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;
    store.subscribe(() => {
      if (isMounted) {
        setState(store.getState());
      }
    });

    // cleanup function to prevent calls to setState on an unmounted component
    return () => {
      isMounted = false;
    };
  }, [store]);

  return <p>{state.value}</p>;
};
```

[CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-accessing-state-8iee3?file=/src/App.js)